# Android apply styles for different screens

Tags: android, styles, screen, resolution

I have an application, that need to run in 2 different devices:
`600x1024` & `480x800`.

For these devices, I want to apply different styles (they has different ratio).
How I can do it, as both of them has hdpi?, e.g. `values-hdpi`, `values-mdpi` have no effect....

P.S. `Android 2.2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the available [resource directory qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers). There are also screen size qualifiers you can use.

In your case you need the `large` and `xlarge` qualifiers. Try that.

Comment: Thanks man, looks like I missed that I can use also large and normal. xlarge would not work, as it's Android 2.3 feature. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if you can use the `normal` as 480x800 should already be `large`.