# Font size outgrows while having small screen with HDPI/MDPI resolution

Tags: android, screen, font-size, screen-resolution

I am trying to support all kind of screen resolutions. When I have small screen but HDPI resolution, buttons/fonts are going out of shape. Because, I have bigger font size for HDPI screens and it goes smaller with LDPI screens. But, when small screen has HDPI resolution, android picks font size from hdpi folder and messes up font size. It becomes big and outgrows the screen width/height.

What is the best solution for such cases ? Is there any option to create folders like values-small-ldpi, values-small-hdpi (basically specifying both screen size and resolution) ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to that is yes (that is, you should be able to create `values-small-hdpi`, etc. folders). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4562292/321697) seems to support that as well.

Here is a full list of qualifiers: [Resource Directory Qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers)

Comment: I just tried using values-small-hdpi. It did not work. Android is still picking up from values-hdpi. I tried values-small too. That did not work as well.

Comment: did you give small screen support TRUE & any density TRUE in manifest.xml ?

Comment: I have not added any restriction specific to screen size/resolution in the manifest file. So, do I need to add any of these specific grants (small screen support TRUE & any density TRUE) there ?